# Error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier

Tags: c++

The line in question is:

> extern BOOL logged_in;

Here are my includes:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT    0x0403              // Very important for critical sections.
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN                 // Good to use.
#pragma optimize("gsy", on)                 // Global optimization, Short sequences, Frame pointers.
#pragma comment(linker, "/RELEASE")         // Release code
#pragma comment(linker, "/opt:nowin98")
#pragma comment(linker, "/ALIGN:4096")      // This will save you some size on the executable.
#pragma comment(linker, "/IGNORE:4108 ")    // This is only here for when you use /ALIGN:4096.
#pragma comment(linker, "/ALIGN:4096")      // This will save you some size on the executable.

//default headers
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Winsvc.h>
#include <winuser.h> 
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib") 
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib") 
#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "shell32.lib")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the original code, but use code function on the editor instead of `<pre>` tags. That way the <s will be displayed right.

Comment: I'm pretty sure bad things happen if you include `winsock2.h` after `windows.h`.  I seem to recall `windows.h` pulling in an older version of the sockets API and causing conflicts galore.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the line in the above code, but "missing ‘;’ before identifier" means that you are missing a semicolon before that line.

Comment: The line above that is:
extern char cfg_loginpass[];

Comment: I'm guessing the compiler error is on the BOOL, so he's missing a header.